# Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Лифт**

В торговом центре этажи нумеруются так: …, –3,–2,–1,1,2,3, … (нулевого этажа нет!). Вася спустился на лифте с этажа с номером A на B этажей, а затем поднялся на лифте на C этажей. Требуется определить, на каком этаже он оказался.

**Входные данные**

Вводятся три числа A, B и C. A — целое число от –100 до 100, не равное нулю. B и C — натуральные числа, не превосходящие 100.

**Выходные данные**

Выведите одно число — номер этажа, на котором окажется Вася.

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
if a<0:
    if -(a-b)>c:
        print(a-b+c)
    elif -(a-b)<=c:
        print(a-b+c-1)
else:
    if b>=a and -(a-b)<=c or b<a:
        print(a-b+c)
    elif b>=a and(-c)>(a-b):
        print(a-b-1+c)
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос? Код не работает или что?

Comment: Код читать невозможно. Вам PEP8 запретили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так, можно подрезать, но пока неохота копаться. Дела...

stack = range(-100, 101)

i = 0

#

while i != 1:

```
a = int(input("Где стоит Вася:"))

if a > -100 and a in stack:

    i = 1

else:
    i = 0
```

i = 0

#

while i != 1:

```
b = int(input("Сколько этажей спускаться:"))

if a - b in stack and b > 0 and b <= 100:

    x = a - b

    i = 1
elif a - b < -100 and b > 0 and b <= 100:

    print("Вася пытается спуститься ниже -100-го
```

этажа. Он спустится только на -100-й этаж.")

```
    x = -100

    i = 1

elif b <= 0:

    print("Второе число должно быть больше
```

ноля!")
        i = 0

```
elif b > 100:

    print("Число не должно быть больше 100")

    i = 0
```

i = 0

#

if x == 0:

```
x = -1
```

#

while i != 1:

```
c = int(input("Сколько этажей подниматься:"))

if x + c in stack and c > 0 and c <= 100:

    x = x + c

    i = 1

elif x + c > 100 and c > 0 and c <= 100:

    print("Вася пытается подняться выше 100-го
```

этажа. Он поднимется только на 100-й этаж.")

```
    x = 100

    i = 1

elif c <= 0:

    print("Третье число должно быть больше
```

ноля!")
        i = 0

```
elif c > 100:

    print("Число не должно быть больше 100")

    i = 0
```

#

if x == 0:

```
x = 1
```

print("Вася на {0} этаже".format(x))

Comment: Используйте форматирование кода через символы \`\`\` в начале и конце куска кода, или кнопку `{}` в панели редактора

Answer (score 1):

Если не мудрить, то достаточно подкорректировать реальный номер подземных этажей и вернуть назад.

```
if a < 0:
    a += 1  
a = a - b + c
if a <= 0
    a -= 1
```

Всё.